# javascript Dataviews and / or typed arrays duplicate the memory x original arraybuffer?

Tags: javascript

I have an arraybuffer of 65536 bytes.
In case I create a dataview(arraybuffer) or a typedarrya(arrabuffer) ... the memory spent by browser grows or not ? That is, is it created a copy of the arraybuffer data?
I think it doesn't by I want to be sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [`DataView`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataView) and (the various types of) [`ArrayBufferView`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView) are *views* on the underlying [buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBuffer). Multiple [typed arrays can share a buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), and creating a new one from an existing buffer will not copy the data. Of course, the memory might grow a tiny bit for creating the View instance.